# Are split-complex and dual numbers considered integral domains? If no, why?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, complex-numbers

From available definition of integral domain I concluded that it is a ring where we can divide by almost all elements, but not all. There are non-zero elements by which we cannot divide.

This seems being satisfied by the both numerical systems. So, they should be integral domains.

Comment: Integral domains have no zero divisors. Both of the rings you mention do have zero divisors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither the split complex numbers nor the dual numbers form integral domains.

For the split complex numbers, where $j^2=1$, the elements $1+j$ and $1-j$ are two nonzero elements having a product of zero, so they are zero divisors.

For the dual numbers, where $\epsilon^2=0$, the element $\epsilon$ is a nonzero nilpotent element, so it is also a zero divisor.